# Totally/Ultimate Distraction Free Mode (Shift + F11)

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Как в SublimeText сделать боковые стороны чёрными в Distraction Free Mode (Shift + F11)?

То есть, чтобы выглядело вот так:

[image]

вместо:

[image]

(На код на скриншоте не обращайте внимания — это просто пример, на этом месте мог бы быть любой текст.)